# Python extracting multiple values from the same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I am bit new to Python. I am dealing with a problem I want to call the key `['name']` and get the following result:

```
['Tom', 'Mark' 'Pam']
```

However i seem to be in a little trouble due to multiple dictionaries in a list as seen in the code bellow.

```
people = [
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10},
{'name': "Mark", 'age': 5},
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7}
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [i['name'] for i in people if 'name' in i]
['Tom', 'Mark', 'Pam']
```

Comment: Given that `'name'` exists in every inner dict, `[i['name'] for i in people]` would be enough

Comment: @BhargavRao `>>> [i['a'] for i in people]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
`

Comment: @BhargavRao ahan! .... :D

Comment: @BhargavRao yep, really! i understand that ,!